# C - Destroy function w/ 2 structures

Tags: c, struct, hashtable, free, destroy

I'm working on a destroy function for my program but I'm having trouble implementing it because my structures are mixing me up. I have two structures: 1 for the `<key, value>` pairs and another for the array, table size, and counter. Here is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "symTable.h"
#define DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE 61
#define HASH_MULTIPLIER 65599

typedef struct Node
{
    char *key;
    int *value;
    struct Node *next;
} Node_T;

typedef struct SymTable
{
    Node_T **Table;
    int tablesize;
    int counter;
} *SymTable_T;

SymTable_T SymTable_create(void)
{
    SymTable_T S_Table;

    S_Table = malloc(sizeof(SymTable_T *) * DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE);
    S_Table->Table = (Node_T **) calloc(DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE, sizeof(Node_T *));

    return S_Table;
}

void symTable_destroy(SymTable_T symTable)
{
    SymTable_T *p, *nextp;
    int i;

    assert(symTable != NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (p = symTable[i]; p != NULL; p = nextp)
        {
            nextp = p->next;
            assert(p->key != NULL);
            free(p->key);
            free(p);
        }
    }
    free(symTable);
    return;
}
```

but this doesn't work for many reasons. Can someone explain how I can go about freeing everything in both structures? The syntax has me very confused. Do I need to (should I) free counter? Should I do one structure at a time or should I be freeing the Node when I am at each index in the array? Thanks guys.

Comment: Unless you show where your allocations are taking place, then all we can do is guess how to free the memory. Are we to *assume* both `key` and `value` are allocated for each node, or is `value` simply a pointer?

Comment: `p` is a pointer to `SymTable_T`, which itself is a typedef of `struct SymTable *`, so you need to dereference it twice and it does not have members like `next` or `key`. Are you sure that this is your exact code?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes, assume key and value are both allocated already.

Comment: It's extremely confusing having `SymTable_T` be a pointer type, but `Node_T` is not.  I strongly recommend not using pointer typedefs; instead make `Symtable_T` the struct type and write `SymTable_T *` when you want a pointer.

Comment: You should probably post your creation code too, it's hard to say what should be freed when we can't see what you allocated.  The question could be answered by saying that you must call `free` once for each time you called `malloc` (and with the same address)

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to determine exactly the memory layout you are trying to free without also seeing how the memory was allocated. Based on your comments you are allocating memory for an array of `symTable` (element initialized `NULL`), a number of pointers to `struct Node` (`Table`) which are initialized `NULL` and from which the list of nodes are allocated with separate allocations for `key` and `value`. You are holding the *starting address* to the list of nodes in `Table`.

Assuming that `symTable` is an allocated *array* of `struct SymTable`, and that memory is allocated for each node of type `struct Node` in the pointer to pointer to type `Node_t` (`struct Node`) named `Table` for each element in `symTable`, and that both `key` and `value` are allocated, you could try freeing the memory associate with each list `Table` in each element of `symTable` with something like:

```
void symTable_destroy (SymTable_T *symTable)
{
    for (i = 0; i < DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE && symTable[i]; i++)
    {
        struct Node *p = *(symTable[i]->Table); /* pointer to node  */
        while (p != NULL)               /* for each allocated node  */
        {
            struct Node *victim = p;    /* pointer node to delete   */
            free (victim->key);         /* free key for node        */
            free (victim->value);       /* free value for node      */
            p = p->nextp;               /* set p to next node       */
            free (victim);              /* free node memory         */
        }
        free (symTable[i]->Table);      /* free Table memory        */
    }
    free (symTable);     /* free allocated array of struct SymTable */
}
```

Above the pointer `victim` points to the current node to be deleted allowing `p` to hold the address of `nextp` and remain valid after the current node is deleted. Give this a go and let me know if you have problems. If you have any issues, edit your question and post the full code showing the allocations and I am happy to work with your further.

Comment: I have added my `create` function which holds memory allocation info. I tried implementing your code but I am getting several warnings and errors.

Comment: OK, you have shown where you allocate the pointers `S_Table->Table = (Node_T **) calloc(DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE, sizeof(Node_T *));` (which should be simply `S_Table->Table = calloc(DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE, sizeof(Node_T *));` ), but you have not shown where you allocate memory for each node. Good job on using `calloc` to insure the pointers are allocated `NULL`, that is an assumption I made in my answer. Can you post your entire code? I can certainly do more with a minimum complete verifiable example I can compile. See: [**How to create a MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)